# How to make if else statement to make sure coding on login.java more secure?

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, authentication, secure-coding

**My problems :**

> **1. I want to make login more secure with if else statement**
>
> **2. But, I have some problem that, whoever fill the form can access the Welcome page.**
>
> **3. I have to add on what coding to make sure that the user that have register on my database only can access my Welcome page.**
>
> **4. Help me, I already find a lot of answer of this problem but all of them cannot function.**

Below is my .java file  : **Login.java**

```
package com.example.lab3;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity
{
EditText username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void OnLog(View view)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        String Username = username.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Background bg = new Background(Login.this);
            bg.execute(type, Username, Password);

            if(Username.equals("") || Password.equals("")) //for user doesnt fill the form
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password are required!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (bg.login(Username, Password))  //I have some error at login
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class));
            }
            else {  
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class)); //can access Welcome.class while the user's account is not available on phpAdmin database.

            }
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

public void OnReg(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class));
}
}
```

My connection database : **Background.java**

```
package com.example.lab3;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Background(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://172.20.10.4/LoginLab3.php";
    String reg_url = "http://172.20.10.4/RegisterLab3.php";
    if (type.equals("login")) {
        try {
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(type.equals("register"))
    {
        try {
            String name = params[1];
            String surname = params[2];
            String age = params[3];
            String username = params[4];
            String password = params[5];
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("surname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"ISO-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Comment: Provide your Background class code the problem is there not here.

Comment: I already added the Background.java